# PHP session seems not to keep posted form values

Tags: php, forms, session

Ladies and gents,

I found a very strange behavior which I cannot explain:

Assume that you have

- multiple form elements on your page, maybe rendered by php
- each form has one input field with an unique name
- on the beginning of that page a session will be started
- you store every posted input value in the $_SESSION variable

like this:

```php
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["Test"] = "Hello";
  foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
    //echo "_POST: " . $name . ":" . $value . "<br>";
    $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    //session_commit();
  }
  for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    echo "<form action=\"multiform.php\" method=\"post\">Value for input $i: <input type=\"text\" name=\"input".$i."\"></form>\n";
  }
  print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

If you use the above code, only the "Test" = "Hallo" will persist after the refresh of the page. Regardless which input value has been posted and stored into the session by the foreach, it will be gone after refresh.

Now the interesting part:

If you add a name to the form like this...

```
echo "<form name=\"form$i\" action=\"multiform.php\" method=\"post\">Value for input $i: <input type=\"text\" name=\"input".$i."\"></form>\n";
```

...the posted values will  be stored then.

But why?
What has the form name to do with the persistence of the $_SESSION?

**EDIT: If the input name only contains numbers, the problem seems to arraise:**

```
<input type=\"text\" name=\"$i\">
```

Thanks for clarifyng this.
Jan

**EDIT2:**

If the accessor key for the $_SESSION array only contains numbers, php obviously does not persist the values, so something like this, won't be stored:

```php
<?php
session_start();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++)
{
  $_SESSION[$i] = "Hello $i";
}
?>
```

The confusing part is, if you do a

```
print_r($_SESSION)
```

just after the for loop, it will show 1-10 with Hello 1..10...
Though, after refresh it's gone...

Comment: Hmm. Maybe, it is the browser, who stores values in forms. And `session_start` may clears the session on each reload (not sure, never used sessions). Try testing in different browsers.

Comment: I did. all the same.
But I just found out, that if the input names only contain numbers, they won't persist in the session!

Comment: What's in multiform.php? I tested this by sending the form directly back to self and it works.

Comment: I had a similar problem once.  Turned out, there was something huge stored in a session - and for whatever reason nothing more would fit.  What does `print_r($_SESSION)` outputs?

Comment: sorry to mention: multiform.php was the file containing exactly this sample code.

The print_r returns Test and the PHPSESSID, which indeed remains the same.

Comment: It looks like the problem was raised by the input names which in my first attempt to reproduce only contained numbers like 1, 2, 3 and so on.
Can someone try this?

Comment: Pressing ENTER in the input field does ;)

Comment: OK, after yet more testing, I found out, that the accessor key of the $_SESSION array must not contain numbers only!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The keys in the $_SESSION associative array are subject to the same limitations as regular variable names in PHP, i.e. they cannot start with a number and must start with a letter or underscore.

Found at http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: The only confusing thing was, that after doing a print_r on the $_SESSION, it printed out the values!

Comment: These values ​​are in $_SESSION variable only during the execution of the script. They are not stored. PHP fire 'PHP Notice' when you're trying to write incorret value into $_SESSION.

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be the integer as a form name as your edit comment suggests? If you serialize a form using PHP you end up with a variable which name is an integer and PHP's variable name cannot be a plain number. If your problem doesn't persist with a naming convention such as `<input type=\"text\" name=\"sometext_$i\">`, you should stop using plain numbers as a form element name.

It's also a good idea to give the form fields descriptive names. Form field named "1" or "2" doesn't really tell you anything about the containing value.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct; [you can not use a numeric-only key](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) in `$_SESSION`. Trying to do so with error_reporting on highest level and display_errors set to true will yield a notice:

```
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Skipping numeric key 0 in Unknown on line 0
```

It does store it in the $_SESSION array, but not actually in the session. Although strange behaviour, the notice is descriptive enough. The fix is easy, by the way, just create an array in `$_SESSION['numbers']`, for example.

```
<?php
session_start();

for ($i = 1; $i < 10; $i++) {
   $_SESSION['numbers'][$i] = "Hello $i";
}

var_dump( $_SESSION['numbers'] );
```

Comment: Your explanation is little better, but you're second. Sorry.

Comment: I had to write more ;)  No worries, mate.